# Euler's Method - Spring Oscillations in MatLab

Tags: matlab

If I've got a second-order differential equation in terms of a first-order differential that describes a mass-spring-damper system, how can I use Euler's method to plot this equation when I don't know the first-order differential?  I'm wanting to do this in MatLab.  This is a homework question so I haven't posted any code.. I just want a brief outline of how you're meant to do it.

The second-order derivative is d2(t+1) = (-1/m)*(c*d1+k*y) where c, m, k are constants, y is initially 1 and d1 is the first-order differential that starts at 0 and t is the time.

Any ideas?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd order eqn can be converted to a system of first order differential equations.

```
function dy = ex(y)
dy = zeros(2,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -c/m*y(2) - k/m*y(1);
```

From this you can use Matlab's in-built solver.  `ode23s` would work just fine:

```
[t,y] = ode23s(@ex, y0, tspan)
```

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the second order equation as a system of first order equations. The unknowns correspond to position and velocity.

Answer (score 2):

A system of first order differential equations could look like this whereas `y1 = y`. `'` is used to indicate the time derivative.

```
y1' = y2
y2' = -c/m*y2 - k/m*y1
```

Comment: Thank you.  How does y2 get defined in the first place?  I want to put these equations in a loop and plot them when I've finished iterating... :)

Comment: @imperial: The implementation can be seen in JudoWill's post. As we are working with a second order system, we need two state variables. The introduction of 'y2' is part of the solution/pattern of rewriting a differential equation as system of first order differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

There is an analytic solution of the form (x(t),x'(t)) = exp(A t)*(x(0), x'(0)), where A is a 2x2 matrix.  If you aren't required to use matlab's ODE solver, this is the right way to find the time evolution of the system.

To find A, write your system in this form

- X = (x, x')
- dX = A * X
- X = expm(A t) X(0) %note that to take the exponential of a matrix, you need to use expm, otherwise you just get the exponential of each element individually

so here A = [0 1; -k/m -c/m]

setting k/m = 1, and c/m = 0.1, we can write

```
t = linspace(0,20, 1000);
A = [0 1; -1 -0.1];
for j = 1:length(t); x(j,:) = expm([0 1; -1 -0.1]*t(j))*[1;0]; end
plot (t,x)
legend ('position', 'velocity');
title ('underdamped spring starting at y = 1; y'' = 0')
```